# U-SQL Join failing

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

Hi I am trying to join using U-SQL and the three input files are text file now I am getting error. I am new into these.
When I am trying to join then it is throwing below error. I have already tried with this: USING `Extractors.Csv(encoding:System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));` but same error.
Could you please help to fix the error :

```
{
    "errorCode": "2703",
    "message": "Error Id: E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR, Error Message: syntax error. Expected one of: identifier quoted-identifier variable . Error Id: E_CSC_USER_RESERVEDKEYWORDASIDENTIFIER, Error Message: Reserved keyword FROM is used as an identifier.. Error Id: E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR, Error Message: syntax error. Expected one of: '(' ANTISEMIJOIN BROADCASTLEFT BROADCASTRIGHT CROSS EXCEPT FULL FULLCROSS GROUP HASH HAVING INDEXLOOKUP INNER INTERSECT JOIN LEFT LOOP MERGE ON OPTION ORDER OUTER OUTER UNION PAIR PIVOT PRESORT RIGHT SAMPLE SEMIJOIN SERIAL UNION UNPIVOT WHERE WITH ';' ')' ',' . ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "U-SQL1"
}
```

U-SQL Script

```
@customerData = EXTRACT 
    Customerid string,
    Name string,
    City string,
    State string,
    Country string,
    Account_Created string
FROM "/a_test/customer_data/[dbo].[customerData].txt"
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);


@productData = EXTRACT 
    Product string,
    Price string,
FROM "/a_test/product_data/[dbo].[productData].txt"
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);


@transactionData = EXTRACT 
    Transaction_date string,
    Product string,
    Payment_Type string,
    Customerid string,
    Name string,
    City string,
    Account_Created string,
    Last_Login string,
    Latitude string,
    Longitude string
FROM "/a_test/transaction_data/[dbo].[transactionData].txt"
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);

@result = 
SELECT 
    t.Customerid,
    t.Transaction_date,
    t.Product,
    t.Payment_Type,
    t.Name,
    t.City,
    c.State,
    c.Country,
    p.Price,
    t.Latitude,
    t.Longitude
  FROM @transactionData AS t
  INNER JOIN @productData AS p on t.Product = p.Product
  INNER JOIN @customerData AS c on t.Customerid = c.Customerid
  order by t.Customerid;

OUTPUT @result TO "/a_test/final_output"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@productData = EXTRACT 
Product string,
Price string,
FROM "/a_test/product_data/[dbo].[productData].txt"
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
```

You have a comma (,) after Price string column, you should delete that one.